# Add a usercontrol as the value of a html attribute

Tags: asp.net

I am working in a CMS where we use tokens (  which is turned into a user control.   Is there a way to add the user control into an attribute value for our template style?

example :

```
<div class="<$tokenName/$>" />
```

this currently outputs an encoded user control, which is then not parsed by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: this is not possible.

Longer answer...
It's not IIS's job to parse the control... that happens when IIS hands off the request to the ASP.NET engine.  ASP.NET does a single-pass parse through your ASPX before the Page lifecycle even starts... this is why controls you delcare in the ASPX are available during the Init event.  Whenever your CMS expands "$tokenName", you are far past the point at which ASP.NET is interpreting your markup.

If you're having trouble with that, here's a thought experiment for you: What happens when $token expands into a user control that has some other $token2 control embedded in it?  And that control contains some other $token3?  How many times are you going to try and parse/expand/interpret your markup?